# RFT Datapool Setting

Tags: rft

Does `RFT` have limitations on how much data can be set into the form, using datapool?

We are reading data from CSV files and it contains 70 columns each for two users, and data is set into forms. We are supposed to get 227 rows for each user in database after processing the page (i.e after running), but we are getting 227 rows for one user and only 87 rows for the other.

On the other hand, when we do it with other type of form (which has 46 columns in CSV files), it gets executed correctly and enter 163 rows per user into the database, which is correct.

Is there any setting for the limit of a datapool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RFT datapools don't have such a tiny limit, so it must be something related with your script. 
You can try to write a simple script which iterates your "large" datapool and print each record to System.out to confirm this.